# redirect std output of a c function to null

Tags: c, redirect, output

I have a C function that generates output, presumably using printf or similar. How do I redirect the output such that it won't be generated while executing that function, and restore it afterwards? Something like below.

```
int main()
{
  // disable output
  c_function(); // generates output
  // enable output

  return 0
}
```

Comment: You want to redirect the output from within your program, e.g. from the caller function?

Comment: So, why not using a flag passed in parameter to `c_function()`? Then inside the function you just check if the flag is set or not. If so, you print, if not, then you don't.

Comment: Assume I dont have access to that function

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the function itself, e.g. by providing an additional output file descriptor, this should work:

```
int outfd;
int savefd;

fflush( stdout );                           // make sure everything is written to 1
savefd = dup( 1 );  // dup stdout for restore
outfd = creat( "mystdout.txt", 0666 );      // create an output file
dup2( outfd, 1 );                           // dup that fd to stdout
functionWithPrintf( );
fflush( stdout );                           // make sure everything is written to 1
close( outfd );;
dup2( savefd, 1 );
printf( "Back again\n" );
```

Comment: Sorry, I posted the answer accidentially before being ready! Now it's complete (I hope. at least :-))

Comment: it's still printing :)

Comment: @Asblarf it should. `dup2()` is defined to close `filedes2`

Comment: @Bob, you're right I've tested it and there was a `fflush()` missing after calling the function. Adding that, my test progam worked as expected.